# How to find mean length per turn (MLT) for magnetic design from ferrite cores datasheet?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, inductor, magnetics

Mean length per turn (MLT) is an important design parameter in **K*g*** method of inductor design as described in the book "Fundamentals of Power Electronics" by Dr. Robert Erickson. [image: Thisis a screenshot from the book.]

Where is the MLT mentioned in [this datasheet](https://www.es.co.th/Schemetic/PDF/FDK-FERRITE.PDF) for EE cores on page 21?

How is the formula derived in the screenshot from the book by T.Mclyman?

**By Robert Erickson**
[image: Robert Erickson]

**By Mclyman**
[image: Mclyman]

Comment: Calculate the circumference from the average diameter ie smallest & largest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to calculate the MLT yourself, based on the core geometry, the bobbin or insulation you wind it on, and the window fill - the amount of copper wire you're putting in, so it isn't a constant for a given core.

For a cylindrical wind, this is fairly easy, since it's just the length of the winding halfway out of the hollow cylinder formed by the winding.

For a rectangular core, you have to break the coil down into geometric segments.

[image]

The first wind has four sides, each the length of the core center pin size pluse twice the insulation thickness, and four corners, which are each the length of a 90 degree arc struck around the corner, remembering that the mean diameter is halfway out - the "A" dimension. The D and E dimensions in the reference are actually C and D in the datasheet, and the A dimension will be (E-D-twice the insulation thickness)/2 *if* the winding window is full, or it'll be just half the depth of the winding layers if it's less than full.

Add these segments together, and you'll get the formula in your reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind effort to explain and for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the linked data sheet and, the first diagram of a core they give is this (with my red lines on it to show what an average turn might look like): -

[image]

Can you see that the diameter of that average turn could be calculated as: -

$$\dfrac{E}{2} +\dfrac{D}{2}$$

Or, if the core isn't fully utilized then use a smaller length but go no smaller than a diameter of D plus a little bit (former dependent) and, don't forget to multiply by \$\pi\$ to get circumference.

Comment: Respected sir ,using your approach gives somewhat different results compared with the values given in the textbook by Sir Erickson. I have found a method to find MLT in the book by T.Mclyman which gives results near to that in the book by Erickson. For example for EE-19: Erickson MLT=3.69cm,  By Mclyman formula = 3.4715(that formula is for bobbin but I calculated for corei.e ignored F), and by your approach MLT=2.9359. Ishare the screen shots of the references in the question again. If you understand the Mclyman approach please make it clear for me as I don't understand the formula.

Comment: They may have adopted a more complex layering technique than just stacking one layer on top of the other - their technique may have been more complex for different reasons but, the discrepancy is big so given that I don't have the reference material, I'm stuck.

Comment: Respected sir could you please check the updated question.

Comment: That's a square section bobbin - my answer detailed a round section bobbin. Clearly, with a round cable trajectory it uses \$\pi\$ and the discrepancy might be explained by that.

Comment: Also, on page 20 and 21 there are 3 different type of EE19 core and I calculate the middle sized one (EE19/15) to be about 38 mm for a nominally central square loop circumference i.e. 4 sides of 9.54 mm length per side. Given that the corners can be rounded you'll lose another couple of mm bringing you down to 3.6 cm. Your table suggests 3.69 cm.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious time and help.